# How can I get a Path object from a String property using SpEL

Tags: java, spring, spring-el

I have a String property set in my application.properties set like this:

```
something.some-path="something/somewhere"
```

And I want to convert it into a Path object using SpEL. I tried doing it this way, but it doesn't work:

```
class SomeClass {
    @Value("#{T(java.nio.file.Paths).get('${something.some-path}')}")
    private Path pathINeed;
}
```

Is it possible, and if yes what am I missing?

Comment: How exactly it doesn't work? What error you get?

Comment: Also `#{` doesn't have matching `}`.

Comment: ahhh i am dumb... thank you, but it still gives me No qualifying bean of type 'SomeClass'

Comment: But on your class definition i see no Spring annotation. How do you define the `SomeClass` bean? Do you use XML based Spring annotation? Do you create it in `@Configuration` (Spring Configuration) class?

Comment: "No qualifying bean of type 'SomeClass'" seems irrelevant to your question. If you comment `@Value` do you still get that error?

Comment: Yup @AngeloImmediata thank you I forgot to annotate the class. I did some changes and forgot to revert them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OP appears to have had [other things](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54212079/how-can-i-get-a-path-object-from-a-string-property-using-spel#:%7E:text=Yup%20@AngeloImmediata,them.) that were giving him problems, but his original attempt is precisely how to create an instance of `Path` from the `application.properties` file:

```java
    @Value("#{T(java.nio.file.Paths).get('${something.some-path}')}")
    private Path pathINeed;
```

It uses [SpEL (Spring Expression Langauge)](https://dzone.com/articles/beginners-guide-to-spring-expression-language-with) and `Paths.get()` to create a `Path`.